# Why do xdebug and the DBGp client vim plugin fail to debug PHP?

Tags: php, vim, xdebug

I have configured xdebug and installed a vim plugin to debug PHP. The link of this plugin is http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1929.
But once I open a PHP file and press F5, it opens that PHP page from a remote pc, an error is shown, and the debug fails at this place. There is no step in or step over, why?

The detail of the error message is as follows:

```
waiting for a new connection on port 9001 for 5 seconds...
connection from  ('127.0.0.1', 48460)
Connection closed, stop debugging (<class exceptions.ImportError at 0xb7a6f3ec>, <exceptions.ImportError instance at 0xb7a047ec>, <traceback object at 0xb7a1
102c>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather old plugin that seems to be using out of date [python libraries](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DBGp-client/blob/master/plugin/debugger.py). However, there seem to be some newer plugins available:

1. [DBGPavim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4059)
2. [DBGp Remote Debugger](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2508)